# iPhone make parent view match view frame after rotation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview, uigesturerecognizer

I have a parent UIView which contains a child UIImageView.

I rotate the child view by an arbitrary amount.

I would now like to make the parent view frame fit the child new frame.

I've tried using sizeToFit on the parent view but it doesn't seem to work.

```
-(void)rotate:(UIRotationGestureRecognizer*)gesture {

    if(gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        lastRotation = 0.0;
        [parentView sizeToFit];
        return;
    }

    CGFloat rotation = 0.0 - (lastRotation - gesture.rotation);

    CGAffineTransform currentTransform = imageView.transform;
    CGAffineTransform newTransform =     CGAffineTransformRotate(currentTransform,rotation);
    [imageView setTransform:newTransform];
    lastRotation = gesture.rotation;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try vise-versa... Instead of rotating the child view you rotate the parent view and the child view will rotate along-with the parent view. Add the Gesture recognizer to the parent view instead of the child view.
Hope this might solve ur problem.

Comment: Problem with this is that i'm trying to capture a screenshot of the rotated image view - which means that I need it in a parent view with no transforms (I think) ...?

Comment: Then y do u want to rotate the parent view?? You can rotate the child view n then take the screenshot of the parent view w/o transformation.

Comment: I don't - I want to rotate the child view and then match the parent view frame to the child views new frame. After rotation, the child view becomes larger than the parent view, as a result, the resulting screenshot gets cropped.